# Joining 2 tables, one GUID with dashes, one without

Tags: sql, t-sql, guid

I am trying to join several tables - the problem is that the GUID in one of the tables does not have the dashes.

What I have found in my research so far was this way to convert a single guid:

```
DECLARE @uuid VARCHAR(50)

SET @uuid = 'ecd5bc3f5cf741acabbbf0fb17634970'

SELECT  CAST(

        SUBSTRING(@uuid, 1, 8) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@uuid, 9, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@uuid, 13, 4) + '-' +

        SUBSTRING(@uuid, 17, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@uuid, 21, 12)

        AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);
```

But how can I use this to join the tables based on the result?
Or is there a completely different way?

Comment: Why are you storing guids in a `varchar` in the first place? There's a specific data type for them, `uniqueidentifier`.

Comment: The table was set up by the software of an external company, so I don't really have any influence on the setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do the join is to convert to strings:

```
select . . .
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.uuid = replace(convert(varchar(36), t2.uuid), '-', '')
```

I should note that this makes optimization difficult.  You might want to modify your first table to have a uuid column with the correct type:

```
alter table t1 add uuid_correct as
    (convert(uniqueidentifier,
             substring(@uuid, 1, 8) + '-' + substring(@uuid, 9, 4) + '-' + substring(@uuid, 13, 4) + '-' +
             substring(@uuid, 17, 4) + '-' + substring(@uuid, 21, 12)
            )
    );
```

You can persist the column and build an index on it.

Comment: I will try the first part, thank you. Updating the table is not an option because the data comes from the software using the table

Comment: @ChrisW If you have control over the _other_ table you could add a _persisted computed column_ to it with with `VarChar(32)` version of the UUID and index it. Either way should improve performance of the `join`.

Comment: I was finally able to try this and it worked. Thank you!